# How can I created a PIL Image from an in-memory file?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-models

More specifically, I want to change the filetype of an image uploaded through a Django ImageField.

My current thinking is to created a custom ImageField and overwrite the save method to manipulate the file.

I've having trouble getting an in memory file to because a PIL Image instance.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that Django's `ImageField` inherits the `open` method from `FieldFile`. This returns a stream object that can be passed to PIL's `Image.open` (the standard factory method for creating `Image` objects from an image stream):

```
stream = imagefield.open()
image = Image.open(stream)
stream.close()
# ... and then save image with: image.save(outfile, format, options)
```

See [PIL Image documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

Comment: `stream.close()` will dump the reference to the file? If I wanted to do `stream.thumbnail(200x200, 'png')` how should I manage `stream.close()`?

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried StringIO ?

see the docs http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm#more-on-reading-images

```
#Reading from a string 
import StringIO

im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(buffer))
```